# Javascript string replace space with no-break space after a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have specific word (for example "in") after which I want to replace a space with a no-break space. I used plain replace: from **" in "** to **" in" + String.fromCharCode(160)**.

However words are not always surrounded by spaces - for eample in this sentence:

*This is sample text (**in** which there are parentheses).*

So I need a regex to replace a space after **"in"** with a no-break space. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a word boundary before `in`

```
.replace(/\bin /g, "in" + String.fromCharCode(160))
```

To make it case insensitive:

```
.replace(/\b(in) /ig, "$1" + String.fromCharCode(160))
```

Here is [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB1hE0/1)

See demo below:

```js
console.log(
    "In this is sample text (in which there are parentheses)."
     .replace(/\b(in) /ig, "$1" + String.fromCharCode(160))
);
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. How can use a variable instead of "in"? I tried `new RegExp("\b(" + preposition + ") ", "ig");` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Using the constructor is the right way, just the backslash must be doubled: `new RegExp("\\b(" + preposition + ") ", "ig");`

Comment: Oh, I see - I have to escape the backslash to make the string literal express "\b" because otherwise the first backslash would escape the "b" and wouldn't be passed to the constructor. is it true?